# How to convert activities to fragments and implement swiping using ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have two activities that I want to add swiping functionality to but any of the online  tutorials that I tried aren't working out as I'm not sure how I would implement them into my code.I looked at this tutorial on the Android developer site : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

I know how to enable navigation between activities using intents that seems easy enough.
Could someone show me an example of how to implement swiping in relation to these two activities,including the steps and reason for them:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity3button3);
        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent INT=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                INT.putExtra("hi", "HI");
                startActivity(INT);     
            }
        }); 
    }

 }
```

Second activity:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);



        Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity3button3);

        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent INT=new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);
                startActivity(INT);

            }
        });

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do so you have to move the stuff from `onCreate` to `Fragment`'s `onCreateView` method
and use a `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layouts from xml.Then the rest is pretty much same.
Just the stuff you do top Views must be moved to onCreateView.

For Paging  there are a lot of examples in internet. You can do it with [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)